# UpdateView form_valid is not redirecting as expected - keeps saying form_valid?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-testing

I've got a Django `UpdateView` that I am trying to test against. The `UpdateView` only accepts post requests, handles the form and redirects the user appropriately depending how the form submission went.

The test fails, but if I run the local server, it works as I would expect. I'm not sure if it's an indication that my test is setup wrong - or if the test is exposing some weird bug.

My view looks like this:

```
class TressleUpdateView(UpdateView):
    http_method_names = ["post"]
    form_class = TressleForm
    model = Tressle
    pk_url_kwarg = "tressle_id"
    raise_exception = True

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed. We set the
        updated_by to the requestor to know who updated this.
        """
        # Ensure the tressle is at a point to be finalized
        # If not, add a message informing the user that the tressle is not
        # complete, and redirect to the summary detail page.
        if form.instance.progress() < 100:
            messages.error(
                self.request,
                _(
                    "The tressle is not complete. Please ensure that all "
                    "requirements have been met."
                ),
            )
            return redirect(
                reverse_lazy(
                    "myapp:tressle-detail",
                    kwargs={
                        "tressle_id": self.kwargs["tressle_id"],
                    },
                )
            )
        # Get the requestor Person object
        request_person = get_object_or_404(
            Person, id=self.request.user.person_id
        )
        # Set the updated_by user
        form.instance.updated_by = request_person
        messages.success(
            self.request,
            _("The tressle has been finalized and is no longer editable."),
        )
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy(
            "myapp:tressle-detail",
            kwargs={
                "tressle_id": self.kwargs["tressle_id"],
            },
        )
```

My test looks like this:

```
    def test_view_redirects_if_tressle_incomplete(self):
        """
        Test that the view redirects to the tressle detail page 
        with the appropriate message if the
        tressle is incomplete.
        """
        self.client.force_login(self.app_user)
        response = self.client.post(
            self.incomplete_tressle_update_url,
            data={
                "finalized": True,
                "rubric": self.incomplete_tressle.rubric.id,
            },
            follow=True,
        )
        messages = list(response.context["messages"])
        self.assertEqual(len(messages), 1)
        self.assertEqual(
            messages[0].message,
            "The tressle has been finalized and is no longer editable.",
        )
        
        self.assertRedirects(
            response,
            reverse_lazy(
                "myapp:tressle-detail",
                kwargs={
                    "tressle_id": self.tressle_person.id,
                },
            ),
        )
```

The `tressle` that is being updated in the test has a `progress()` of 0.0 - and is 'incomplete', yet when the test runs - this is the output:

```
AssertionError: 'The tressle is not complete. Please ensure that all r[22 chars]met.' != 'The tressle has been finalized and is no longer editable.'
```

I have dropped into the debugger in the test and can see that it is hitting the appropriate redirect and getting the error message, but the code is not stopping there and continues on to hit the `super().form_valid(form)` but I'm not sure why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure this is your correct code?  The test asserts that the message text is equal to `The summary has been finalized and is no longer editable.`, but the test results appear to instead be looking for the text `The tressle has been finalized and is no longer editable.`, i.e. the second word is `summary` instead of `tressle`.

Comment: Sorry! I updated the code. Had wrong word in there from a little refactor. The example code is updated.

Comment: The form validation method checks `form.instance.progress() < 100`.  As far as I can see, the test does not set this value.  (The test does set `finalized=True`, but the form does not appear to use that input item.)

Comment: @JohnGordon the `.progress()` method is determined by a set of related models (which none are created in the `.setUp`; so the `.progress()` is 0.0. I know this because I've put breakpoints in the test to drop into the debugger to ensure that `.progress()` is not 100.